# Report off SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

I have a SharePoint 2013 list.  This is On Prem.  The list has a notes section.  I run a report daily that pulls certain fields from that list, including the note section.

I am having a formatting issue.  Whenever a user types a `"&#58:"`, the report shows it as ":".  I tried using REPLACE in the expression builder for the report.  It is not working for me.

Can anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: What you mean by `Whenever a user types a ":", the report shows it as ":"`?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of how it looks for you?

Comment: I'm not seeing how to add the screenshot.  @Amal, Whenver a colon is typed, it show up as "&#58:" on the report, instead of a colon.  Thank you for pointing out that I typed it wrong.